# Generalised dot and cross products

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

Are the dot and cross products in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ specific examples of a more general operation that is defined on arbitrary dimensional vector spaces? And if so are there any physical applications of these more general operations?

Comment: Well there is geometric algebra that says for two vectors, $\mathbf a\mathbf b=\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b+\mathbf a\wedge\mathbf b$ which is called a bivector. Is this the sort of thing you’re looking for?

Comment: This is very broad. For example, we could start talking about tensor products, with the cross product defined as the dual of a tensor product. Or we could talk about quaternions; both the dot product and the cross product can be subsumed within the quaternions (which predates the vector-scalar system and can be seen as including it). Or we could answer no and say that the dot and cross products are the only rotationally invariant multiplication operators in the vector-scalar system.

Comment: For the cross product, it can only be defined as a binary operator in 3, or 7, dimensional space. There is no 4 dimensional cross product. However the 3d cross product is a special case of what is known in general as the "Exterior product". For the dot product look into the more general ideas of an "Inner product" as well as Tensor contraction

Comment: Thanks for the responses, what is special about 7 dimensional vector spaces that allows the cross product? And does no other vector space up to $\Bbb R^{\infty}$ have a cross product in the same sense?

Comment: @Charlie: better use the wedge-product. It always works. (except may be $\infty$-dim. Hilbert space. At least I've never seen it there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot product -- also called scalar product --- can be defined in every finite $n$-dimensional space. So it for instance exists in the Minkowski-space which is 4-dimensional, although one has to account for the non-euclidean metric. It is very often used in relativistic invariant expressions, for instance between two 4-vectors, for instance $x=(t,x,y,z)$ and $p=(E,p_x, p_y, p_z)$ (we assume speed of light $c=1$):

$$p\cdot x = Et-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}$$

And as physicists already develop theories beyond the 4-dimensional space-time, it is also present in those higher-dimensional spaces. In Quantum mechanics the generalization of the dot-product is defined as bilinear form on the $\infty$-dim. Hilbert space. Briefly said, it is ubiquitous.

The story about the generalization of the cross-product is a bit more subtle. As generalization one uses the $\wedge$ (wedge)-product which is defined on the exterior algebra (also called Grassmann-algebra) of totally anti-symmetrical tensors.  One defines spaces $\Lambda^p$ whose basis are exterior products of standard base vectors $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ of a n-dim.   vector space $V$:

$$\{ e_{i_1}\wedge\ldots \wedge e_{i_p} | i_1 < \ldots <i_p  \}\,\,\text{basis of}\, \Lambda^p \,\, p\leq n$$

$\Lambda^0$ is the set of real numbers and $\Lambda^1$ is the vector space $V$.
Then you can define the exterior product of 2 vectors $v=v^j e_j\,\, \text{and}\,\, w=w^k e_k \in V$ (summation over double appearing indices):

$$v\wedge w = \frac{1}{2!} (v^j w^k - v^k w^j) e_j \wedge e_k$$

and

$$v\wedge w =-w\wedge v$$

Special feature of the exterior wedge product of 2 vectors $\in V\equiv \Lambda^1$: 
The result no lies in $V$, but in $\Lambda^2$. But in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the result can be mapped back from $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to $\Lambda^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$. For this exists the Hodge operator $\ast$ which realizes a mapping from $\Lambda^p$ to $\Lambda^{n-p}$. I will not explain it now in detail how this operator works but only say that

$$\ast (e_1 \wedge e_2) = e_3\,\,, \ast (e_1 \wedge e_3)=-e_2\,\,\text{and}\,\,\ast (e_2 \wedge e_3)=e_1$$

Of course the hodge operator is defined in any $n$-dimensional space. All this exterior algebra looks rather complicated, and actually it is, but once acquired is extremely useful. It most often used with differential forms and I give only one example of its utility: multi-dimensional integration: In a for 3-dim. integral one has typically:

$$ \int f dx dy dz $$

which is actually

$$ \int f dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$$

which is very useful upon coordinate change and subsequent computation of the Jacobian determinant. I just give you a very little flavor of it, if interested you have to look it up yourself in the corresponding textbooks.
BTW, the wedge product is used in General Relativity.

Comment: Really informative thank you very much!